# TypeError: 'range' object does not support item assignment how to fix this

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

```
avail = range(n_connections)
for i in range(0,n_entities):
    for j in range(0,n_connections):
        if avail[j] != -1: #checking availability
            if (((dat[j][1] == 1)|((dat[j][1] == 11))) & (dat[j][2] == i)):
                if ((dat[j][3] == 3)|(dat[j][3] == 13)):
                    avail[j] = -1 # here error is coming how to fix this 
                   # n_connections = len(connectionx - 1)
                    for k in range (0,n_connections):
                        if avail[k] != -1: #checking availability
                            if (((dat[k][1] == 3)|((dat[k][1] == 13))) & (dat[k][2] == dat[j][4])):
                                avail[k] = -1 # booking
```

Comment: read [ask].....

Comment: Any code with 4+ levels of indentation is wrong, no matter how right you think it is.

Answer (score 1):

In Python 2, `range()` returns a regular list of integers, but not in Python 3.

If you want `avail` to be such a list, then do this:

```
avail = list(range(n_connections))
```

Comment: TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()

Comment: TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len() this error coming

Comment: My sample code has no `len()`.  Do you mean the commented-out line `n_connections = len(connectionx - 1)` in your question?  If so, what type of object is `connectionx`?  If it's an integer, then that's the problem.  You can't take the `len()` of an integer.